# Forced screen orientation when connecting via ADB

Tags: android, adb

Whenever i connect to any device via ADB, the screen orientation is set to auto rotate.

```
adb = Client(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
devices = adb.devices()
adb.remote_connect("192.168.178.31", 5555)
device = adb.device("192.168.178.31:5555")

device.shell('input touchscreen tap 537 869')
```

So as soon as i would run the shell command, the device would be set to auto rotate. How would i either set the default device orientation to portrait, or fix the problem otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
device.shell('settings put system user_rotation 0')

device.shell('settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0')
```

You can choose the value that corresponds to the desired orientation by `user_rotation` (0 for portrait, 1 for landscape)

Instead of you can change `accelerometer_rotation` for disable or enable rotation (0 stay current, 1 rotate screen)

Comment: The crucial thing i was missing is, you have to set it after every start of an application because otherwise the rotation will be set again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Disable auto rotation

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

#### Force landscape

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1
```

#### Rotate back to portrait

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

#### Upside down

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:2
```

#### Rotate to landscape, right

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:3
```

This is how it works in setup wizard in android. Auto rotate is set to disable(0) during the setup until we press "Finish" then autorotate is set to active again. `adb shell settings` wont work on the "fly" so it's better to use `adb shell content` for doing such things:

```
Utils : backupDefaultScreenOrientation, set auto rotate 0
07-16 13:28:36:953 Utils : restoreDefaultScreenOrientation, set auto rotate 1
```